# Angular JS Switcharoo multiple select module

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have created a script for going a multiple select option in Angular without using a `select` box that you have to hold control in order to select multiple items.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/xfw9f/

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/qwertynl/AngularJS-Switcharoo/tree/9866f0485d9055465d65371b8a139aeebd9e9747)

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
var switcharoo = angular.module('switcharoo', []).directive('multiSelect', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            default: '=',
            leftTitle: '@',
            rightTitle: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "switcharoo.html",
        link: function(scope)   {
            scope.switchItem = function(item)   {
                var index = scope.default.indexOf(item);
                if(index == -1) {
                    //add it in
                    scope.default.push(item);
                }
                else    {
                    //remove it
                    scope.default.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
})

switcharoo.directive('switchitem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{value}}</div>'
    };
});
```

HTML Template:

```
<style>
    .switchBox .entBox {
        overflow:auto;height:8em; width:190px;border:1px solid black;float:left;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox div:hover {
        background-color: #908f8f;
    }
    .switchBox .eBox2.entBox {
        background-color: #ccc9c9;
    }
</style>

<label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>{{leftTitle}}</th>
            <th>{{rightTitle}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="switchBox">
            <td>
                <div class="entBox eBox1">
                    <switchitem ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-if="default.indexOf(key) == -1" value="value" ng-click="switchItem(key)"></switchitem>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="entBox eBox2">
                    <switchitem ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-if="default.indexOf(key) > -1" value="value" ng-click="switchItem(key)"></switchitem>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</label>
```

Is there anything I can do to make my code slicker?

Answer (score 2):

I really like your code, I only have 2 minor observations:

- I understand the part where `default` has the default items. I am not sure that after initialization you should keep referring to the `default` variable ( from a naming perspective ), maybe call it `selection` instead of `default` ?
- Related to the previous point, `ng-if="default.indexOf(key) == -1"` and `ng-if="default.indexOf(key) > -1"` only make sense during initialization. In my mind, it would be ideal to provide a `isSelected( key )` that you can use for the `ng-if`. Not to mention that it will remove a `>` out of your HTML attribute and look better in Markup ;)

Comment: Yea, I realize now that it should be called "selected" and not default. I'll try using a function instead for the `ng-if`

Comment: Does this look better? http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/xfw9f/15/

Comment: If you go for slickness, then I would go for `return ~scope.selected.indexOf(item);` other than that, looks good to me.

Comment: What does the tilde (`~`) do?

Comment: Bitwise NOT, converts -1 to 0, convert anything else to not-zero,

Comment: idk if I want to do that. It is a little hard to read and understand if you do not know what it does.

Comment: NO worries, just a suggestion ;)

Comment: I just updated the [Github code](https://github.com/qwertynl/AngularJS-Switcharoo) with code from the fiddle